# How to fix the issue "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key"

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, uefi

**Problem:** I have just finished performing a clean installation of windows 10 to my laptop (Using command prompt from windows recovery environment).

Every time I want to use it I have to access Boot manager and tap the option "launch efi shell from filesystem device" OR "Windows Boot Manager" from the Boot manager list in order to proceed to windows Operating System.

**Question:** What causes this problem and how to fix it (any method)?

Comment: Check your BIOS settings. In particular **boot mode** and **boot sequence**. Looks like you are in a legacy mode while your windows is installed in EFI.

Comment: I dont have a boot mode settings but my boot order is: Hard Drive -> CD/DVD ROM. is legacy mode is same as Legacy USB Support? if so, I disabled it while installing windows 10 and booted my flash drive from the boot manager option "launch efi shell from filesystem device".